# How does C read bytes using the read syscall?

Tags: c, filesystems, system

I need to read an `unsigned short` using the `read` system call.
According to [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> read() attempts to read up to `count` bytes from file descriptor `fd`
>          into the buffer starting at `buf`.

In my case, an `unsigned short` is two bytes size, so it can store the numbers up to 65535. But when I execute this code:

```
char buf[2];
bytes_read = read(0, buf, 2);
bytes_wrote = write(1, buf, 2);
```

and type in the command line, say, the number `123`, it returns only `12`. Does it not read bytes, but symbols? How can I read a value with more than 2 symbols into a 2-byte buffer? For example, the maximum values of an `unsigned short`. I found nothing in either K&R or the manpages about it, so I think it's very simple.

Comment: Yes, it reads bytes. It doesn't _parse_ them, just read them. You're getting the first two bytes.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yes I found it, in terminal there many different symbols. It seems to be ASCII interpretation!

Comment: It doesn't matter what encoding. You're typing in `1`, then `2`, then `3`; your code will read the first two of the bytes you wrote. It won't interpret (using ASCII for convenience) 0x31 followed by 0x32 as the number 12; it'll interpret it as 0x31 followed by 0x32.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes thanks for explanation!

Comment: I turned my comment (which I didn't realize was your misunderstanding -- I thought something else was happening) into an answer. If it answers your question, please feel free to accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>NB: I'm assuming your terminal uses either ASCII or UTF8. For the purposes of this explanation, they're equivalent.</sup>

When you type, say, `123`, `read` isn't getting that as a number. It's seeing that as a sequence of bytes -- since you said that it should look to fill a 2-`char` buffer, it sees the first two bytes: First, 0x31, then 0x32. It reads the first byte, and then the second; it doesn't interpret them into numbers. That the series of bytes *happens* to represent a number when decoded as ASCII or UTF8 is irrelevant; all C cares about is the actual sequence of bytes, and that's what it gives you.

Note that it doesn't even *see* the third byte. That's left in the input stream to be consumed by later input operations.

If that's what you want, great! If you wanna get a number typed out (i.e. that's been entered as a string of bytes whose values align with a decimal number), take a look at [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and its related functions.